# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: java, mysql

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main(TimezoneDump.java:70)
```

I get this error no matter what I do. I use MySQL Workbench, I've changed the password for the root user, I've granted all rights to the user root, I've tried to disconnect and connect again to the database. Nothing, no matter what I do. Could you please help me solve this? I don't know what else to do. The password an username are both correct.

**Java code:**

```
package Restaurant;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class MainApp {
    public void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {

        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema";
        Statement sql;

        ResultSet rs;
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");

        sql=(Statement)con.createStatement();
        rs=sql.executeQuery("select * from restaurant");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("Nume: "+rs.getString("nume")+", Specific: "+rs.getString("specificul")+", Zona: "+rs.getString("zona"));
        }


        rs.close();
        sql.close();
        con.close();
    }

}
```

[Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPer4.png)

Comment: Did you set the root account / password for "localhost" (127.0.0.1), or for some other hostname?

Comment: For what it is worth, the exception message is saying that no password was supplied, and that the user name was the empty string.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I set it for local host, I've put a SS in the post with Administration-Users and Privileges

Comment: Please do not post code and error messages as screenshots.

Comment: OK, I will keep that in mind. I've put the code, but as for the user configuration I can't put snippets of code as it is from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: `DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");` doesn't seem to match `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. Are you sure that this code is what generates this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your eclipse is running the class "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump" (which also contain a main method) instead of your MainApp class.

Try this manipulation:

```
Right click on MainApp.java -> Run As -> Java Application
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but I don't have the option Run as Java Application, I only have Run in Server.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Your main method is not correct.
-> public ***static*** void main(String[] args)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I didn't even notice! It works now.